# read tab separated file with multiple words

Tags: java

i have tab separated file with 3 columns
for example:
(tab) = tab separation, it doesnt written in file

hello (tab) merhaba (tab) n
after (tab) sonra (tab) n

and im creating array using this method:

```
public static void fileToArr() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(dictionary);
        dictionaryArray.clear();
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            dictionaryArray.add(scan.next());
        }
    }
```

but my file can have multiple words in 1 column, for example:
hello friend (tab) merhaba (tab) n
after (tab) sonra (tab) n

and then everything breaks, because scan.next() scans next word, but i need to scan next word by tab separation. Is it possible?

I already wrote everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches white space. In order to change the delimiter, you can use the method `useDelimiter​(String pattern)`.

```
public static void fileToArr() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(dictionary);
    scan.useDelimiter("\t");


    dictionaryArray.clear();

    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        dictionaryArray.add(scan.next());
    }
}
```

#### Note

You should edit your text file using a proper text editor. I used IntelliJ IDEA to edit my text file first. Even though I did add a tab after some space separated words, scanner was unable to do its job properly.

I switched to vim and that did the trick.

Comment: You should probably be closing that `Scanner` with try-with-resources

Comment: Yes, I agree. I only made the changes in the user provided code and gave the solution for the problem.